# How to find compatible memory with mac mini mid 2010

Tags: mac, memory

Here's the apple doc on it:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4223

says it needs:

```
PC3-8500 DDR3 
unbuffered
non-parity
204-pin module
1066 MHz
```

Googling around, seems like this gives me a list of compatible options (I can't post more than two links without 10 reputation, so):

amazon.com/gp/search?ie=UTF8&keywords=DDR3%20PC3-8500%20204-pin&tag=iclarified-20&index=blended&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=9325

How do you pick which one to go with? For example, this is the #1 hit:

[http://www.amazon.com/Crucial-PC3-8500-SODIMM-204-Pin-CT2K4G3S1067M/dp/B008LTBJFM/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1412702783&sr=8-1&keywords=DDR3+PC3-8500+204-pin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008LTBJFM)

what's the difference with the other matches?

Also, none of them mention the:

```
unbuffered
non-parity
```

points like in the apple kb article. Not sure if that's a problem.

Thank you

Comment: Crucial, Kensington & Corsair all have memory finders, either by drilling down menus to find the model or by running a downloadable app

Comment: oops - Kingston, not Kensington - fixed & added as answer with links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Crucial](http://www.crucial.com), [Kingston](http://www.kingston.com/en/memory/system_specific) & [Corsair](http://www.corsair.com/en-gb/memory) all have memory finders, either by drilling down to find the model or by running a downloadable app.